# INNER JOIN and using GROUP BY to prevent duplicate results?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to join CTE and another table (`temp.holder`) to get unique records but somehow I am not getting unique records and I am not able to figure out what's wrong. I see lot of them are duplicated.

Below is my query:

```
with data as (....)
select cola, date_part(week, trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'PST8PDT', starttimestamp)) + 6) as colb, colc, cold, cole, colf, colg, colh, coli, count(*) as process_type
from data join
     temp.holder x
     on data.cola = x.cola
where colj NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
AND colb = extract(week from current_date) + 1
group by data.cola, starttimestamp, colc, cold, cole, data.colf, colg, colh, coli
order by data.cola;
```

But when I run this query, I don't see any duplicates.

```
with data as (....)
selec * from data;
```

Is there any problem in my first query?

Also how should I go ahead and debug out what's wrong in my first query? As of now I dump output of my query in csv file and then I use my python script to figure out if there are any rows being duplicated.

I am trying to convert this:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    COLF    COLG    COLH    COLI    COLJ
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
a1      b1      c1      d1      e1      f1      g1      h1      i1      PART
a1      b1      c1      d1      e1      f1      g1      h1      i1      TYPE
```

into this:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    COLF    COLG    COLH    COLI    process_type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a1      b1      c1      d1      e1      f1      g1      h1      i1      2
```

**Note:** I am dealing with 80k+ rows. Also `starttimestamp` column is timestamp without time zone column.

Comment: What is the actual output based on the 2 record input you showed above?

Comment: I see `ColA-ColI` values same for all the rows but count is different for some reason for all those rows and that is puzzling me a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is `group by data.cola, starttimestamp,` - each row has its own timestamp and therefore each 'group' is actually just one row. Instead you'd want to group on the week-component of it?

Comment: @seanb when you say week component - can you tell me what I should be using? I am kinda confuse here.

Comment: ColB is `date_part(week, trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'PST8PDT', starttimestamp)) + 6)` - I suspect you want to group by that, rather than starttimestamp on its own. (I don't use redshift so I'm not 100% what that's doing, but I'm guessing it's getting the week number/component of the timestamp once converted to UTC).

Comment: I tried grouping by `colb` instead as well but then I see `process_type` count is way too high for all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `group by`.  You are grouping on the original time column rather than the calculated one in the `select`.  So try this:

```
group by data.cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, data.colf, colg, colh, coli
```